# How to link to text file in HTML for script use

Tags: javascript, html

What I'm after is this idea: The document contains some link to a text file (for load order reasons, I have several excessively bulky script and image files as well as a huge wall of HTML and want to get this operation done within 5 seconds even on 5kb/s) and then a script is able to reference this text file (to avoid messy code), a bit like:

```
textFile = document.getElementById ("textFileLink");
someText = textFile.read ();
doSomething (someText);
```

Some ideas I have tried:

1. Use the link toString method mentioned in passing in the [living standard](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/links.html), this merely returns the url itself.
2. Instead have a script which exists solely to dump a 10k character string into a global variable (definitely bad)
3. As above but into a `display:none` HTML element (maybe not quite as bad?)
4. As above but LocalStorage?

is this possible, or do I have to do some kind of server-side black magic?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using the `fetch API`:

```js
fetch('path/to/demo.txt').then((res) => res.text()).then((data) => {
  // code
});
```

Fetch should be relatively quick... tell me if it works or if there are errors

Comment: Not working in my local test sandbox due to the fact Chrome won't allow local fetching for some reason, I'll have to see if I can persuade the backend devs to give me a little test page and file on our servers but looks like it should work.